# My Angular's Output Event Emitter handler isn't triggered

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I'm trying to change a part of my website when someone click on a svg picture.
That's why I used EventEmitter : to send the information of which part might be shown.

First, the code of my SVG triggering its own event on a click, and emitting to its parent :
`<div (mouseover)="onMouseOver()" (mouseout)="this.onMouseOut()" (click)="onChangePage()">
...

`
Its ts :

```
...
export class IconTestsComponent extends MenuIconComponent {

  @Output('ChangePage2') ChangePage2 = new EventEmitter<string> ();
  onChangePage() {
    console.log("test")
    this.ChangePage2.emit("tests");
  }

}
```

its parent is triggered, here's its own code:
HTML :

```
<div style="width: 7%; background-color: dimgray; padding: 1%; height: 100%;">

    <app-icon-tests (ChangePage2)="onChangePage($event)"></app-icon-tests>
    ...

</div>
```

TS :

```
export class MenuComponent {
    @Output('ChangePage3') ChangePage = new EventEmitter<string> ();

    onChangePage(new_page: string) {
        console.log("test")
        this.ChangePage.emit("tests");
        console.log("emmited?")
    }
}
```

this is supposed to be triggered (this works) and emit to parent (this doesn't) :
HTML :

```
<div>
<app-menu (ChangePage3)="onChangePage($event)"></app-menu>
<app-edition-page></app-edition-page>
</div>
```

TS :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-editing-page',
    templateUrl: './editing-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editing-page.component.scss']
})
export class EditingPageComponent {

    onChangePage(newPage: string) {
        console.log("triggered?")
        console.log(newPage)
    }
  
}
```

I'm unable to find the solution of this problem, the last one is never triggered...
Do you know why please?
Thanks in advance

(my console result :)

```
test       icon-tests.component.ts:13:12
test       menu.component.ts:12:12
emmited?   menu.component.ts:14:12
```

*edit :*

I've tried to go through by using a Service whith a method I call which toggles my component with a RXJS Subject. Perhaps, my component still doesn't want to listen anything :
My Service's code :

```
export class ShowingPageManagerService {
  private current_page = '';
  public current_page_sub: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  constructor() { }

  ChangeShownPage (page:string) {
    console.log("it sucks");
    
    this.current_page = page;
    this.current_page_sub.next(this.current_page);
    console.log("still sucking");
  }
}
```

and here's my component's one :

```
ngOnInit(){
    (this.shownPageService.current_page_sub).subscribe({
      next: (next_page) => console.log("Eureka!")
      // this.onChangePage(next_page)
    });
  }
```

I've already try to make ChangeShownPage as async, still not working...
Is that possible to my component to be "bugged" or am I just the most unlucky man ?

Answer (score 0):

In the html you are expecting ChangePage3 but you have no emitter called like that.

```
export class MenuComponent {
    // Output variable ChangePage should be ChangePage3
    @Output('ChangePage3') ChangePage = new EventEmitter<string> ();

    onChangePage(new_page: string) {
        console.log("test")
        this.ChangePage.emit("tests");
        console.log("emmited?")
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Output ('ChangePage3)`
Might change the name for the EventEmitter, isn't it?
I also tried with ChangePage, with ChangePage3 it's not compiling (type error, the EventEmitter is't a string type, but an event type, because undefined in my child class) , and without I still have the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Alright, was just a little mistake : I forget to change my app-component.html, I never used the parent component, that's why it didn't work.. sorry for that..